# S3: Move all files from subdirectories into a common directory

Tags: amazon-s3

I have a lot of subdirectories containing a lot of images (millions) on S3. Having the files in these subdirectories has turned out to be a lot of trouble, and since all file names are actually unique, there is no reason why they should reside in subdirectories. So I need to find a fast and scalable way to move all files from the subdirectories into one common directory or alternatively delete the sub directories without deleting the files.

Is there a way to do this?

I'm on ruby, but open to almost anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added a comment to your other question, explaining why S3 does not have folders, but file name prefixes instead (See [Amazon AWS IOS SDK: How to list ALL file names in a FOLDER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329234/amazon-aws-ios-sdk-how-to-list-all-file-names-in-a-folder/9330600#9330600)).

With that in mind, you will probably need to use a combination of two S3 API calls in order to achieve what you want: copy a file to a new one (removing the prefix from the file name) and deleting the original. Maybe there is a Ruby S3 SDK or framework out there exposing a rename feature, but under the hood it will likely be a copy/delete.

Related question: [Amazon S3 boto: How do you rename a file in a bucket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481685/amazon-s3-boto-how-to-rename-a-file-in-a-bucket)