# Renaming a file on S3

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, boto

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Rails or Django? (or something else?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91846/rails-or-django-or-something-else)
>   [Amazon S3 boto: how to rename a file in a bucket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481685/amazon-s3-boto-how-to-rename-a-file-in-a-bucket)

I am using this:
http://django-storages.readthedocs.org/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html

I need to rename a file, how can I do that?

I searched the docs thoroughly and couldn't find anything.

Comment: Perhaps that has been changed in the past two years?

Comment: You can see the underlying operations exposed by S3 here: http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectOps.html -- the only basic operations exposed are upload, download and delete.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use copy operation see http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/CopyingObjectsExamples.html. Using the copy operation, you can:

- Create additional copies of objects
- **Rename objects by copying them and deleting the original ones**
- Move objects across Amazon S3 locations (e.g., Northern California
  and EU)

Comment: In the original question, @azio mentioned using django-storages. Using S3 via django-storage you cannot rename the file in S3. That must be done independently using the above techniques.

Answer (score 3):

SubRed is absolutely correct to rename then S3 Object.

If you do this without writing a single line of code then you can use Bucket Explorer, It does rename the complete folder (all objects start with common prefix end with "/").

[**Disclosure** : I am developer of Bucket Explorer]