# how to mass change folder names in amazon s3 with a script

Tags: unix, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I uploaded a bunch of images but accidentally named the folders with spaces. Now you can't access them cause obviously urls cant have spaces.

I've downloaded the aws cli and was wondering how to change folder names? I've looked at the documentation but I'm still having trouble and hoping someone can help.

I've tried the below command without any success:

`aws s3 mv "s3://mybucketname/firstfolder/second folder with spaces/" s3://mybucketname/firstfolder/secondfolderwithspaces/ --recursive`

How do I change the name of "second folder with spaces" to "secondfolderwithspaces"?

Also, is there a way I can iterate through these folders? Something like

```
for folder in s3:/bucketname/firstfolder: 
     aws s3 mv "folder with spaces" folderwithspaces --recursive
```

Comment: What error are you getting? I am able to use the mv command to accomplish this operation.

Comment: You can also replace the spaces by some `+` to get rid of this without renaming your folders

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd do it via a python script using the boto SDK:

```
import boto

conn = boto.s3.connect_to_region('ap-southeast-2')
bucket = conn.get_bucket('bucket-name')
for k in bucket.list():
  if ' ' in k.key:
    bucket.copy_key(k.key.replace(' ', '+'), bucket.name, k.key)
    bucket.delete_key(k.key)
```

The script loops through each object, copies it to a new key (which is like a filename, but it includes the full path including the directory name), then deletes the old object. It fully executes within Amazon S3 -- the contents of the objects are not downloaded/uploaded.

Modify the replace command to suit your needs.

Answer (score -1):

URLs can have spaces. You have to encode them. Space character becomes "%20".
If you have chrome or firefox, open the developper tools console, and type

```
encodeURI("second folder with spaces")
```

It prints

```
second%20folder%20with%20spaces
```

For the mass rename, it can't be done in the same way as you traditionally would on an OS (Linux/Windows/Mac). On S3, you cannot rename files, you must copy them. So you have to download their content, delete them, and new files.

[Amazon S3 boto: How do you rename a file in a bucket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481685/amazon-s3-boto-how-do-you-rename-a-file-in-a-bucket)